# How to set menus in Mezzanine Django

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I have created a *model.py* file in which I define my classes like:

```
from django.db import models
from mezzanine.pages.models import Page

class Author(Page):
    dob = models.DateField("Date of birth")

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey("Author")
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to="authors")
```

Then my HTML page and place it into `templates folder` define URL in *urls.py* file.

I run command `python manage.py collecttemplates` to get all templates

Now I browse `127.0.0.1/8000/page1/` to get my page view.

****Question 1: How to place this page in menu of home page using admin interface?

Question 2: How to solve this error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'` generates if I browse `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/conf/setting/`?

Question3 : How to access POST DATA from forms created in mezzanine interface?****

UPDATE:

```
from django.db import models
from mezzanine.pages.models import Page
class Author(Page):
    dob = models.DateField("Date of birth")

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey("Author")
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to="authors")
```

and admin.py with these:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from mezzanine.pages.admin import PageAdmin
from .models import Author
```

admin.site.register(Author, PageAdmin)

Now i write these commands: python manage.py syncdb,  python manage.py migrate,
and then open python shell to write  Author.objects.create(dob = "12/12/2014")

**That generates error that author is not defined. It's true because no tables created in my database.?!**

Comment: I think for question 3 you're looking for the processor_for method: http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/content-architecture.html#page-processors

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're working through the Content Architecture tutorial on the Mezzanine site. The tutorial assumes a lot on your part, which is not ideal for a beginner. If you haven't seen it, you might want to take a look anyway. Here it is: http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/content-architecture.html

To answer Question#1: You add the new content type via the Pages admin: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/pages/page/` Select from the drop-down menus that read "Add..." to select its type and on the following configuration page you can select where you want it displayed as a menu link.

In response to your UPDATE:

At the Djanog/Mezzanine Python shell:

```
from <your app> import models
```

Then try models.Author.objects.create(title="Dr. Seuss")

No ideas on Questions #2 & #3 right now.